# Dictionary with String as Key and Generic Class as value

Tags: swift, generics

I have sockets and plugs, plugs are of any generic type. Now i want to store a Plug of any type into a dictionary. I tried to declare the possible type of the Plug in the dictionary in all ways i can think of. None worked. I do only find solutions for passing any Value T but not a class of any generic type. Also i fear my usage of words is not right in all cases. What did i name wrong?

Example will clear things up.
So how could i store this Plugs into the dictionary "plugs" of the socket:

```
import Foundation

class AClass {

}

class BClass {

}

class Plug<T> {
    init() {

    }
}

class Socket {
    var plugs = [ String: Plug ]() // should accept any Plug
    init() {

    }
    func addPlug( plug : Plug ) { // should accept any Plug
        self.plugs["A"] = plug // should accept any Plug
    }
}

var plugDouble = Plug<Double>()
var plugString = Plug<String>()
var plugAClass = Plug<AClass>()
var plugBClass = Plug<BClass>()

var socket = Socket()
socket.addPlug(plug: plugDouble ); // should accept any Plug
socket.plugs["A"] = plugDouble // should accept any Plug
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a base class (let's call it `BasePlug`) that all `Plug` classes will derive from.  Have your dictionary store items of class `BasePlug`:

```
class BasePlug {

}

class AClass {

}

class BClass {

}

class Plug<T> : BasePlug {

}

class Socket {
    var plugs = [ String: BasePlug ]() // should accept any Plug
    init() {

    }
    func addPlug( plug : BasePlug ) { // should accept any Plug
        self.plugs["A"] = plug // should accept any Plug
    }
}

var plugDouble = Plug<Double>()
var plugString = Plug<String>()
var plugAClass = Plug<AClass>()
var plugBClass = Plug<BClass>()

var socket = Socket()
socket.addPlug(plugDouble ); // should accept any Plug
socket.plugs["A"] = plugDouble // should accept any Plug
```

Comment: That is a workaround/hack. I need to know how to pass a generic class like the Plug to a method and how to declare a dictionary which is able to hold any of this Plugs. For example if i use func addPlug( plug : Plug<AClass> ) { it will work for AClass, but if i use func addPlug( plug : Plug<Any> ) { it won`t work at all.

Comment: Do you want your dictionary to simultaneously hold an item of type `Plug<AClass>` and `Plug<BClass>`?

Comment: Swift dictionary values all need to be the same class.  That is why introducing a common base class to all `Plug`s works.  `BasePlug` is better than `NSObject` since it is at least specific to Plugs.  What about the `BasePlug` doesn't serve your needs?

Comment: Well i will find a workaround that is not the point. The point is also understanding things an such. "Swift dictionary values all need to be the same class" is not exaclty true i think as you can have a dictionary var dict = Dictionary<String, Any>() which will just take anything. Shouldn`t i be able to aply that logic to this case?

Comment: In the case of Dictionary<String, Any>, Any serves as the base class of any class.  The dictionary is still holding only 1 type, in that case type `Any`. Your example would have worked if you had just declared your dictionary to be `[String: Any]` and had `addPlug(plug: Any)`.

Comment: You can write `addPlug` as  `func addPlug<T>( plug : Plug<T> ) {
        self.plugs["A"] = plug
    }` which works if your dictionary holds `BasePlug`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69950/discussion-between-alex-and-vacawama).

Comment: @vacawama What Alex is looking for is very like a specialized Any.  Any is special because it's really two kinds of things - a possible class *or* struct.  In the same way it would be nice to be able to have a container that says I only want it to be possible to hold Any struct of my specified generic type, which seems like a reasonable way to want to limit a collection...  I have another question up which is a similar take on the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406461/swift-how-to-hold-any-possible-instance-of-a-generic-type-in-a-variable/28416319#28416319