# Swift: How to hold any possible instance of a generic type in a variable

Tags: swift, generics

The distillation of what I am trying to do is this:

```
public struct HolderOfWrappers
{
    let anyWrappedItem: MyResource<Any>
}

public struct MyResource<A>
{
    let wrappedItem : A
    let convert: String -> A
}

func holdResource<A>( resource: MyResource<A> ) -> HolderOfWrappers
{
    // Error on this line, A is not Any...
    let wrapHolder : HolderOfWrappers = HolderOfWrappers( resource )
    return wrapHolder
}
```

As it stands, this code produces the compiler error in the last `holdResource` method where I'm trying to build a `HolderOfWrappers`:

```
Cannot convert the expression's type 'MyResource<A>' to type '(anyWrappedItem: MyResource<Any>)'
```

Which is understandable as the code indicates HolderOfWrappers can only hold a MyResource built for Any type, not any possible type.  What I'm really after with the `HolderOfWrappers` is something like this:

```
public struct HolderOfWrappers
{
    let anyWrappedItem: MyResource<>
}
```

or even `MyResource<*>` - I am trying to say with this code that I'd like a variable that can hold any type of MyResource.  If I try to use either syntax though, I get a compiler error that it expects a type.

I could just have `anyWrappedItem` by of type `Any`, but then you lose the type information for future use.  I also do not want HolderOfWrappers to be generic (because then I'd just have the same problem later).

It's almost like I am trying to treat the generic type as a protocol for the `anyWrappedItem` storage variable, which will not work for other reasons...

Comment: Seems actually to be the same situation as mine here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250294/dictionary-with-string-as-key-and-generic-class-as-value
Since MyResource<SomeType> and MyResource<OtherType> seem to be completly unrelated classes form the compilers point of view you will have to wrap MyResource<T> with somethinh like MyResourceBase. But well, that won't work with structs..

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I had not run across that answer in searching SO - I'd rather use a base class than use Any as the storage type... it also lets me have method signatures I can expect.  The struct was on the edge of needing to be a class anyway, sigh.

Comment: Nice to see yet another Swift limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do what you want by putting a generic parameter in your `HolderOfWrappers` `init` method. Basically, the `init` method just generates a new `MyResource` using the `resource` that you provide, like this:

```
public struct HolderOfWrappers {

    let anyWrappedItem: MyResource<Any>

    public init<A>(resource: MyResource<A>) {
        self.anyWrappedItem = MyResource(wrappedItem: resource.wrappedItem, convert: resource.convert)
    }
}
```

I think that will do what you want. I don't know if it will be slower since you are initializing an entirely new `MyResource` instead of just copying one.

At any rate, it makes it so that `HolderOfWrappers` itself is not generic and will fill `anyWrappedItem` with a `MyResource<Any>` that holds the same values as the `resource` that you pass in.

Comment: Very interesting, that appears to work!  I don't mind the copy of the resource since it's a struct, and will be copied all over the place anyway.  I'm surprised though that the compiler is not OK with my setting a resource from outside that's not explicitly "Any" but is OK with essentially the same thing done from the internal init.  Will try on Swift 1.2 also.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
protocol Wrapper {}

public struct HolderOfWrappers {
    let anyWrappedItem: MyResource<Wrapper>
}

public struct MyResource<A> {
    let wrappedItem : A
    let convert: String -> A
}

func holdResource( resource: MyResource<Wrapper>) -> HolderOfWrappers {
    // Error on this line, A is not Any...
    let wrapHolder : HolderOfWrappers = HolderOfWrappers(anyWrappedItem: resource)
    return wrapHolder
}
```

of course the downside is you'd have to do `extension A: Wrapper { }` for any type A that you pass into MyResource.

Comment: An interesting idea but as you point out needing to do the extension is kind of annoying... but if the objects I'm passing into MyResource all implement some kind of protocol anyway, that may be the best idea.  I'll think about that...

Comment: On further experimenting I'm not sure this will work - using those changes even if I have a struct that conforms to Wrapper, I cannot pass in a MyResource of that type into the holdResource call.  It creates a wave of backwards pressure so all genericness is removed and eventually MyResource can only take a Wrapper conforming object - and then I have to remove the MyResource generic type declaration to use it.