# Swift dictionary with UInt8 array as a value

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

Is it possible to declare a dictionary?
Type String as its key, and value with multiple types(String, Int, [UInt8]) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First that came my mind:

```
var content:[UInt8] = [1,2,3]
var arr = [String:Any]()
arr["1"] = 1
arr["2"] = "test"
arr["3"] = content
```

Or you want to get values with type casted?

UPD: Another solution in my mind was to use generics, but then you should realize your own class or protocol for storaging. And find on stack similiar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250294/dictionary-with-string-as-key-and-generic-class-as-value)

Comment: What I want looks like:   array["1"]=1     array["2"]="test" array["3"]=[1,2,3]

Comment: What you missing is [UInt8] array as a value

Comment: @fcbflying updated, it will sure work, because value is `AnyObject`, another array is of course `AnyObject`

Comment: Cool, but if I try this, error will happen:           var content:[UInt8] = [1,2,3]
        var arr = [String:AnyObject]()
        arr["1"]=1
        arr["2"]="test"
        arr["3"]=content

Comment: In Swift, instances of String, Int, and Array are not objects, so they can't be stored as type AnyObject (except when bridged to Foundation objects). AnyObject is just for instances of classes.

Comment: @fcbflying You can change `AnyObject` to `Any` so value can be even not class, and that will work

Comment: @katleta300 Bad thing is ,the dictionary can not be used  for SwiftyJSON when I try JSON(dict), will be error that 'Cannot invoke initializer fro type 'JSON' with an argument list of type '([String:Any])''

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want using a dictionary of type `[String: Any]`.

```
var theDictionary = [String: Any]()
theDictionary["blue"] = "sky"
theDictionary["lucky"] = 7
theDictionary["bytes"] = [UInt8](arrayLiteral: 0x01, 0xFE, 0x54)
```